# Prove $O(x^n) * O(x^m) = O(x^{n+m})$

Tags: real-analysis

${x\to 0}$,$m>n>0$ Prove
$O(x^n)$ $*$ $O(x^m)$ = $O(x^{n+m})$

What I did.

$f(x)$ = $O(x^n)$

$g(x)$ = $O(x^m)$

$\rvert\frac{f(x)}{x^n}*\frac{g(x)}{x^m}\lvert\leq\rvert\frac{f(x)*g(x)}{x^{m+n}}\rvert\leq L*M$

From here we can say that prove is complete?This is my first steps to asymptotic analysis proofs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a small detail that you could be missing.

$f(x) = O(x^n)$ means that there is $x_0$ and $L >0$ such that for $x \geq x_0$, $|f(x)| \leq L x^n$.

$g(x) = O(x^m)$ means that there is $x_1$ (which can be different from $x_0$) and $M >0$ such that for $x \geq x_1$, $|g(x)| \leq M x^m$.

With this, you can conclude that for $x \geq \max\{x_0,x_1\}$,

$|f(x) g(x)| \leq L x^n M x^m = LM x^{n+m}$, where $LM >0$.

Thus, $f(x)g(x) = O(x^{n+m})$.

Comment: @J.G. thanks for the correction of my typos :D